# Is there a tool out there that makes debugging JavaScript and jQuery easier?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, debugging

I'm fairly inexperienced with JavaScript and jQuery, but I need both for the ASP.Net website I'm working on.  I am slowly figuring it out, but I've been relying heavily on StackOverFlow.

Does anyone know of any tool (preferably free) that makes debugging JavaScript and jQuery easier?  I've been using Firebug which has been helpful, but I guess I'm just spoiled by Visual Studio's debugger and intellisense.  Is there anything like that for JavaScript and jQuery?  It would sure make my life easier if there were.

What do you use?  Any recommendations?

Comment: Are you using the Firebug script debugger? If so, how is it not working for you?

Comment: for IE it is IE developer toolbar and for chrome it has Chrome Developer toolbar

Comment: The Firebug plugin for Firefox works, I'd just like to know what else is out there and what other people use.

Comment: google for videos firebug , there are couple of them and they will show you how to debug, it has beutiful net panel which shows all http request etc. Firebug is really wonderful tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (Firefox).  The awesome thing about FireBug is that you can use CSS selectors directly in the console (see [here](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API)) to test some of your jQuery selectors.  You can also find lots of logging functions to use with FireBug (check out the [console API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API))
- [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) (Not as powerful as the full-featured FireBug, but great in a pinch)
- [Chrome Developer tools](http://www.chromium.org/devtools/google-chrome-developer-tools-tutorial) (Chrome; Safari has nearly identical tools)
- [IE Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565622%28VS.85%29.aspx) when you must open IE.
- `window.alert`
- [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net), which is useful for quickly coding and testing JS.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, use the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin for Firefox

Comment: Doesn't he literally say he uses Firebug in the question?

Answer (score 3):

I don't like anything Microsoft, but last time I looked at Visual Studio it was providing IntelliSense for Javascript. You may be interested [in this article.](http://blog.turlov.com/2010/05/leveraging-visual-studio-javascript.html)

You say you're already using Firebug, which is a good start. I'd recommend also debugging in a webkit browser, such as Safari or Google Chrome. Both options have a developer console built in and it behaves much like Firebug. The beauty of jQuery is it does the dirty work of browser DOM inconsistencies between browsers, so if you have pure jQuery working in one browser, it will more than likely work in IE as well. I always make my program work in a standards compliant browser first, and then worry about IE.

IE8 also has developer tools/console or whatever they call it.

Answer (score 3):

My comment can be answer

for IE it is IE developer toolbar and for chrome it has Chrome Developer toolbar. You can even use Fiddler for IE which tells about ajax calls.

Please let me know if you need any other info

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Firebug, using [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) will check and help you write good JS code.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans has a pretty stupendous system from what I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

I like the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=web+developer&cat=all&lver=any&pid=1&sort=&pp=20&lup=&advanced=) addon for Firefox and other browsers.  It's got an error console which is pretty handy.